# How can i obtain a sequence of number equispaced respect to a given scale?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to get a series of point equispaced respect to a function. I mean: i know np.linspace and np.logspace in numpy to create equispaced point in a linear and logaritmic scale, but if i have a curve of point and i want to get a subsequence of this points that are equispaced respect to the curve they belong, how can i do? There is a python module already implemented for this purpose ?

I imagine something like :

```
from scipy import interp1d
def functionspace(starting data, initial_value, final_value, Number_of_point):
    interpolation_curve = interp1d(starting_data)
    total_length =  analitical_length(interpolation_curve)
    distance_between_point = total_length/Number_of_point
    lista = []
    point0=initial_value
    for value in curve:
        if analitycal_length(value-point0)>distance_between_point
            lista.append(value)
            point0=value
    return lista
```

But  there are difficult function to implement like "analytical value"

There is something already implemented?

Comment: Equally spaced along the curve?  That's not easy.  Heck, just figuring out the LENGTH of an arbitrary curve is not easy.  I suppose you could compute the derivative at small increments and gather up an accumulator, then take a hack when you cross a threshhold.

Comment: i tried to use an accumulator but the problem is that when the range become great (and i need often range of 5-6 order of magnitude) the problem become computationally unfeasible. I asked if there were some alghorithm maybe evaluated only theoretically until now, to approach the problem in human time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Assuming this is for plotting, you're not going to want more than 100 points.  If you evaluated the derivative at 10,000 points, that wouldn't be prohibitive.

Comment: I need this for numerical purpose: i'm implementing a data analysis of impedence measures took in 6 order of magnitude different frequencies. The real and imaginary part of the impedence will create a curve known as IMPS spectrum, but to do some numerical analysis (called DTA analysis) it would be fine to interpolate the curve taken equispaced points on the curve. DTA is usually implemented on logspaced data. The problem of logspaced is that in the IMPS curve they tend to accumulate in some regions and be very sparsed in other. I hope to improove the performance of analysis with a trick.